# How to refresh *ngIf after data changes

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am working on my first angular2 project. I have this scenario. If an account doesn't exist, I show the account creation screen. When the account gets created, I set the flag for accountexists to true, but I don't know how to force this logic to be re-evaluated.

```
<div *ngIf="!accountexists">
     <accountcreation></accountcreation>
</div>
<div *ngIf="accountexists">
    <accountdatasheet></accountdatasheet>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this happening when you set this flag in parent component (from account creation child component)?

Comment: I made a stupid mistake. The flag is actually on a service that is shared between the components. I should have been referring to it as accountService.accountExists.

Comment: You might want to look into guards for the router, it might be a cleaner approach to setup a guard that will redirect your user to the account creation component if no account exists.